# Prove that $\sqrt{\det(A^TA)}=\|xｘy\|$

Tags: linear-algebra

If $x,y ∈ \Bbb R^3$ and $A$ is a $2$ by $3$ matrix whose columns are $x$ and $y$.

Is there a way to solve this without solving the square root of the determinant?

Comment: If the matrix consists of two columns from $\Bbb R^3$, then that's a $3\times 2$ matrix, not $2\times 3$.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for typesetting math.

Comment: Note that the determinant here is of a $2 \times 2$ matrix, which means that it isn't so difficult to compute

Answer (score 0):

HINT: use the facts that 
$$\|x\times y\|=\|x\|\,\|y\|\sin\alpha $$
$$x^Ty = y^Tx = x\cdot y = \|x\| \, \|y\| \cos\alpha$$
where $\alpha$ is the angle between the vectors $x$ and $y$.